# how to add search functionality in multiselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two multiple selects in a page (select-cities & chosen-cities), and I can transfer options to and fro. I have given the search functionality to select-cities list. Everything functions as I need.

I need to add the search functionality for chosen cities list also. Can somebody suggest me how to do that. I tried doing it with the same code but it didn't work. Please suggest the solution. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/130/

html:

```
<input id="someinput">
<br/>
<select class="select-cities" name="city" id="optlist" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Frederiksberg</option>
    <option>Vanløse</option>
    <option>Glostrup</option>
    <option>Brøndby</option>
    <option>Roskilde</option>
    <option>Køge</option>
    <option>Gentofte</option>
    <option>Hillerød</option>
    <option>Tårnby</option>
    <option>Vallensbæk</option>
</select>
</input>
<br/>
<input id="someinput1"/><br/>

<select class="chosen-cities" name="chosen-cities-name" id="optlist1" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });


    $('#someinput').keyup(function () {

        var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
        var optlist = $('#optlist').empty();
        opts.each(function () {
            if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
            } else{
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]).addClass("hidden"));
            }
        });
        $(".hidden").toggleOption(false);

    });
    $('.select-cities').click(function () {
        $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
        opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });
    });

    $('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
        $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
        opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });
    });


});

jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};
```

Comment: There's a great jQuery plugin for searchable select lists. its called "Chosen" http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ . You might find it useful.

Comment: and it seems you have only written your function for #someinput but not for #someinput1 . May be that's the problem.

Comment: if you found my comments useful, I have posted it as an answer. So that others would benefit from it as well. Good Day.

Comment: @aayushshrestha I tried to do that, it didn't work. if i try to type in one search box, the other box losses its functionality. There is some problem with keyup() function that i am using. do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great jQuery plugin for searchable select lists. its called "[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)" . You might find it useful.

and it seems you have only written your function for #someinput but not for #someinput1 . May be that's the problem

Here, I have updated your fiddle to solve the problem. All I did was added the function for #someinput1.

$('#someinput1').keyup(function () {

```
var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput1').val(), 'i');
var optlist = $('#optlist1').empty();
opts1.each(function () {
    if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
        optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
    } else{
        optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]).addClass("hidden"));
    }
});
$(".hidden").toggleOption(false);
```

});

And a few tweaks to populate the second select list options.

```
opts1 = $('#optlist1 option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
```

Take a look

[Solved Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/131/)

Comment: :Even i did the same. There is still a problem. when you search in one box and then go on to search in the other box, the search won't function correctly. 

Try to do that: Search in #someinput box, select two three values and without pressing the backspace, move to the other search box i.e. #someinput2, it won't function correctly.

Comment: I think I am not able to replicate your problem. Because I did exactly what you said and its working perfectly fine. Both the searches are working. I hopped back and forth in the two searchboxes. Didnt backspace. tried backspacing too. The search is working fine in every case.

Comment: I did the following steps:

1. first I typed e in #someinput box, and selected three options.
2. the values are now in chosen cities list.
3. Now i tried searching the second search box without deleting the content i typed in the first searchbox.
this where the problem starts. It won't work. If you are free then please try this.

Comment: Yup. I did exactly what you just said. Its working perfectly fine. Are you sure you're checking on the fiddle that I solved? Here's a link anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/131/

Comment: still the problem persists. Well, i guess i am not able to communicate my problem correctly. thanks for your time. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

-> create a multi-select HTML

```
<select id="selectBox" class="select-box" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

-> add search box

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search">
```

-> jQuery to search and select in multiselect

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchBox').on('keyup', function(){
            var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('#selectBox option').each(function(){
                var optionText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var isVisible = optionText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
                $(this).toggle(isVisible);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is all code and does not have supporting explanations of what you're doing.